# Ошибка при использовании пространств имен Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Раньше использовал `yii2 basic`, и проблем не возникало!

Но сейчас нужно использовать `advanced`, но с ним проблема!

*Почему то возникает ошибка с `namespace`, система просто их не видит!*

примером index.php в frontend:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно это исправить ?**

Answer (score 2):

Просто phpStorm не видит содержимое папки vendor. Если редактируете файлы на ftp, то загрузите их еще раз.

Comment: для того чтобы загрузить вендоры на сервер достаточно сделать `php composer install` через консоль, по ftp это долго и непродуктивно :)

Comment: Вы не поняли меня. Вы установили йии на сервер через композер, понятное дело. Но если вы редактируете свое приложение через фтп, то надо к себе на машину засосать не только приложение, но и вендор. Не на сервер, а на комп себе.

Comment: кстати да, на компе в нужной папке запустить в консоле `php composer install`, чтобы система увидела :)